# How to update data in Firebase realtime database using Firebase 9 (modular sdk)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do we do this now:

```
import "firebase/database"

await firebase
        .database()
        .ref('users/' + auth.currentUser.uid)
        .update({
            displayName: displayName
        });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That should do:

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import {update, ref, getDatabase} from "firebase/database"

const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = getDatabase(app)
const dbRef = ref(db, `users/{userUid}`)
update(dbRef, {displayName: "Firebase9_IsCool"}).then(() => {
  console.log("Data updated");
}).catch((e) => {
  console.log(e);
})
```

Comment: The new SDK is just amazing. Import only required things and no namespace like `firebase.database()` or so..

Comment: about time too, lib really needed it